# Number theory: find the value of $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the following problem, you are given three pieces of information. Use them to answer the question.

- $GCF(a,b)= 13\cdot 7$
- $LCM(a,b) = 13^2 \cdot 7^3 \cdot 41$
- $b=13^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 41$
- $a \in \mathbb{N}$

> What is $a$ ?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that LCM$\times$GCD = product of the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

For the solution, it is worth knowing that a * b = GCF(a, b) * LCM(a, b);(If you don't know this, try to prove it(it's easy))
a = GCF(a, b) * LCM(a, b) / b = 4459.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)